# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException what does this mean?

Tags: nullpointerexception

```
public void addEventTime(String eTimesIn) 
{ 
  if (numETimes == eTimes.length) {
     increaseEventTimesCapacity();
  }

  eTimes[eTimes.length - 1] = eTimesIn;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [Docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an
> object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a
>   null object.
> - Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
> - Taking
>   the length of null as if it were an array.
> - **Accessing or modifying the
>   slots of null as if it were an array.**
> - Throwing null as if it were a
>   Throwable value.

I would guess your `eTimes[eTimes.length - 1] = eTimesIn;` is trying to access a null.